# Field Pack - Dropdown does it work with channel:form?

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

Field Pack - Dropdown does it work with channel:form?

I can't make it work! I need to use both "name : label"

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: Michael, please add more details to your question... "I can't make it work" is not enough information. What version of EE, what version of Field Pack, What isn't working exactly? Is it working in the CP but not with channel:form in template? Are there JS errors? Any PHP errors when you turn debugging on or look in the PHP error logs?

Comment: …ok! no errors! with EE's build in "Select Dropdown" I can access the data within the "exp:channel:entries" tags easily using the documentation. But when I try to access the data in the "Field Pack - Dropdown" I just can't make it work! I want to use the "Field Pack" because of the two values it has!

I'll try some more today and see, but it looks like they work a little different!

EE 5.7.2 and Field Pack 2.1.1

Comment: Did upgrading to the latest EE and FieldPack resolve this for you?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version of EE (2.7.2 as of this posting) and Field Pack (2.1.1).